# Bootstrap Carousel. How to reduce the header and indicators on a mobile phone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, carousel, caption, indicator

the size of caption and the round indicators, of carousel, when i tight the window of chrome are the same in mobile and in fullscreen. it's possible to become smaller when i am in mobile?

thanks for the attention and excuse me for the bad english!

Desktop:
[image: full-screen]

Mobile:
[image: mobile]

Comment: It is possible, try detecting size of the window and acting on that information. In Chrome you can simulate that - when you open console, top left button will resize the display.

Comment: @AgataB I guess OP is referring to the standard `768px` breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use media queries to specify another values for CSS properties:

- [Bootstrap's media queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)
- [media queries for standard devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

For example:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel-caption h1 {  /* Header */
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .carousel-caption p {  /* Paragraph */
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li {  /* Indicators */
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
  }  
  .carousel-indicators .active {  /* Active indicator */
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
  }  
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .carousel-caption h1 { /* Header */
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .carousel-caption p { /* Paragraph */
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .carousel-indicators li {  /* Indicators */
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
  }  
  .carousel-indicators .active {  /* Active indicator */
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
  }  
}

.carousel img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/c69/f9c/?text=First" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Paragraph.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/9c6/cf9/?text=Second" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Paragraph.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="//placehold.it/900x300/69c/9cf/?text=Third" alt="">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <p>Paragraph.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```